# Error when installing Constituent Tree Lib in Python

Tags: python, nlp, libraries

I am trying to use the so visually attractive Constituent Tree Lib in Python : https://github.com/Halvani/Constituent-Treelib. I have followed the steps in the installation (pip install, ...), but I get this error :

```
Collecting constituent-treelib
Downloading constituent_treelib-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (17 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: benepar in 
c:\users\... \python311\lib\site-packages (from constituent- 
treelib) (0.2.0)
Collecting contractions (from constituent-treelib)
Downloading contractions-0.1.73-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
Collecting fasttext (from constituent-treelib)
Using cached fasttext-0.9.2.tar.gz (68 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [28 lines of output]
  C:\Users\...\Python311\python.exe: No module named pip
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 38, in __init__
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybind11'
 
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\...\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\...\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\...\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8f9djh2i\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8f9djh2i\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8f9djh2i\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
      super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8f9djh2i\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 72, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 41, in __init__
  RuntimeError: pybind11 install failed.
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
 │ exit code: 1
 ╰─> See above for output.
```

Does anyone know about how to fix the problem? Thanks so much in advance.